# What is the function of "一" in the sentence 要上山，只有这一条路?

Tags: usage, word

I came across this sentence:

> 要上山，只有这一条路

#### Is there a *rule* when to throw in a `一`?

In detail:

1. What exactly is the **function** of `一` in this sentence ?
2. Could I also simply say `要上山，只有这条路` ?

Sometimes I come across some unexpected `一` like in this sentence:

> 人的一生中，究竟什么是最重要的？

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 要上山，只有这一条路。
> To go up the mountain, there is only this 1 road.

Here, 一 is the number 1.  一条路 = "one road" (wherein 条 is a measure word).  So we could change it to any other number, e.g.:

> 要上山，只有这六条路。
> To go up the mountain, there are only these 6 roads.

Replacing 这一条路 with 这条路 above is fine: with [the number omitted](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Measure_word_%22ge%22#Omitting_the_Number), the default quantity is 1.

In 人的一生中, the 一 is part of the word:

> 一生 (yī​shēng​)
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%B8%80%E7%94%9F): all one's life / throughout one's life

If we delete the 一 from the word 一生, we'd obtain [生](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E7%94%9F) which is a completely different word.  So we can't delete the 一 here.

More generally:

1. There are a bunch of words and idioms containing the character 一 (e.g. 一生, 一起, 一样, 一叶障目): by deleting the 一 from within a word, we'll almost always end up with nonsense.
2. There are a number of grammar structures that also use 一, such as [一……就……](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Events_in_quick_succession_with_%22yi..._jiu...%22).  Occasionally it's okay to omit the 一, such as how [一边……一边……](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Simultaneous_tasks_with_%22yibian%22) is sometimes written 边……边…….  However, I'd guess for most grammar structures involving 一, it won't be okay to omit the 一.
3. It's often okay to omit the 一 before a [measure word](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Measure_word): 她是一个孩子 = 她是个孩子 but I don't think it's always okay to omit it: I wouldn't start a sentence with a measure word (e.g. I wouldn't write 一匹马在吃草 as just 匹马在吃草), and omitting it in 一个人 might result in confusion with the word [个人](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E4%B8%AA%E4%BA%BA).